# Viewing boot in serial Console on GCP Compute Engine

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, boot

I am diagnosing a boot process of a custom image on GCP Compute Engine. I am trying to figure out how I can view the boot from the serial console or anywhere else. This is all I see on the serial screen:

```
serialport: Connected to *****-****.asia-southeast2-a.instance-2-serial-tty2 port 1 (session ID: 4661c0157f5758d46a97b560d1b0671cc02ad8b4, active connections: 2).
Total RAM Size = 0x0000000100000000 = 4096 MiB
CPUs found: 2     Max CPUs supported: 2
SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-google)
Machine UUID 3b9f104e-7f4f-14c6-c226-134be788ae90
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=33554432 = 16384 MiB
drive 0x000f22e0: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=33554432
Sending Seabios boot VM event.
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
```

I can boot successfully in VirtualBox, so I can make any changes to the image if required and have tried using other serial ports:

`sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS1.service`

The screenshots for the VM also come up blank black screen.

How do I go about diagnosing the boot for this in GCP? Please advise incase this is the wrong forum for this post.

Comment: How did you migrate your VirtualBox image to the GCP ? What OS you're trying to run ? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what OS you're trying to boot in GCP, but I can take an aducated guess and assume that you've created a VM with a disk from a VirtualBox image and it doesn't want to boot.

If that's all that you're getting from the serial console output it's not enough to troubleshoot.

I recommend going again through this description on [how to import and create a VM from VirtualBox image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#bootable) and try again.

Going back to OS type - make sure it's one of the supported ones - otherwise there's no guarantee it will work. You can find a [complete list of compatible OS'es](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/import#--os) in the documentation.

Comment: @user3599285 Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?